# how to make an Activity scrollable even if no ScrollView is needed?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, scrollview

I have an `Activity` that includes some `RelativeLayout`s arranged vertically in a `LinearLayout`. now I want the user to be able to play with the activity by scrolling it up and down, I mean suppose I have 4 `RelativeLayout`s in a `LinearLayout` in my activity and they only occupy half of the screen vertically, so there is no need for `ScrollView`, but I want to scroll up/down (if the user scrolled up/down) and come back to first position (like an spring!). it's not a new thing and I'm sure you all know what I say! how to do that?

Comment: but ScrollView only scrolls up/down while it is needed and if you scroll up to reach to the head, then nothing happens if you scroll up more (an springy behavior doesn't happen)

Comment: there was a patent issue related to Apple's patent of bouncing list view implementation, so Google removed this feature of ScrollViews, they added blue shadow on edge instead

Comment: That springgy effect is actually a patented UI/UX pattern from apple. There some free libraries that implement similar things but I have primarily seen them applied to ListViews rather than to scrollViews. The overscroll on android is usually indicated by a gradient that shows up when you reach the end.

Comment: interesting, but finally is it possible to do that in Android?!!! if yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

Add an ontouchlistener to your scrollview that wraps your outer linear layout and have the listener handle over scroll. You will have to modify a lot of this to meet your needs but it will provide the basics of how this would work. Or you could go with the fade edge property already in listview and save a lot of time not duplicating the Apple UI.

**Example Touch Listener**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Views.Animations;


namespace SomeProgram
{

public class ViewFlipperSwipeDetector : ParentActivity, View.IOnTouchListener
{


    //private Activity activity;
    private ViewFlipper viewflipper;
    int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;


    public ViewFlipperSwipeDetector(ViewFlipper viewflipper)
    {
        //this.activity = activity;
        this.viewflipper = viewflipper;

    }

   private Animation inFromRightAnimation() 
   {
    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, +1.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f,
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);

    inFromRight.Duration = 400;
    inFromRight.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    return inFromRight;
    }

    private Animation outToLeftAnimation() 
    {
     Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
     Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, -1.0f,
     Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);

    outtoLeft.Duration = 400;
    outtoLeft.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    return outtoLeft;
    }

    private Animation inFromLeftAnimation() 
    {
    Animation inFromLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, -1.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f,
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);
    inFromLeft.Duration = 400;
    inFromLeft.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    return inFromLeft;
    }

    private Animation outToRightAnimation() 
    {
    Animation outtoRight = new TranslateAnimation(
    Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, +1.0f,
     Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f, Dimension.RelativeToParent, 0.0f);
    outtoRight.Duration = 400;
    outtoRight.Interpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();
    return outtoRight;
    }

    protected void onRightToLeftSwipe()
    {
        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "RightToLeftSwipe!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        viewflipper.InAnimation = inFromRightAnimation();
        viewflipper.OutAnimation = outToLeftAnimation();
        viewflipper.ShowNext();

    }

    protected void onLeftToRightSwipe()
    {

       // Toast.MakeText(activity, "LeftToRightSwipe!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        viewflipper.InAnimation = inFromLeftAnimation();
        viewflipper.OutAnimation = outToRightAnimation();
        viewflipper.ShowPrevious();

    }

    protected void onTopToBottomSwipe()
    {
        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "TopToBottomSwipe!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        //activity.doSomething();
    }

    protected void onBottomToTopSwipe()
    {
        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "BottomToTopSwipe!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        //activity.doSomething();
    }


    public bool OnTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                {
                    downX = e.GetX();
                    downY = e.GetY();
                    return true;
                }
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                {
                    upX = e.GetX();
                    upY = e.GetY();

                    float deltaX = downX - upX;
                    float deltaY = downY - upY;

                    // swipe horizontal?
                    if (Math.Abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        // left or right
                        if (deltaX < 0) { this.onLeftToRightSwipe(); return true; }
                        if (deltaX > 0) { this.onRightToLeftSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "Swipe was only " + Math.Abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        return false; 
                    }

                    // swipe vertical?
                    if (Math.Abs(deltaY) > MIN_DISTANCE)
                    {
                        // top or down
                        if (deltaY < 0) { this.onTopToBottomSwipe(); return true; }
                        if (deltaY > 0) { this.onBottomToTopSwipe(); return true; }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Toast.MakeText(activity, "Swipe was only " + Math.Abs(deltaX) + " long, need at least " + MIN_DISTANCE, ToastLength.Short);
                        return false; 
                    }

                    return true;
                }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your code and idea but what is it written in? that's not Java...anyhow it gave me a good start point :);)

Comment: Its c# from a Xamarin.Android project should be pretty easily convertible.